# Power planes splits effect on differential pairs routing

Tags: pcb-design, differential

I'm routing a differential pair (rs485), and I'm wondering if I should avoid routing it above a power plane split. I read about the undesired effects that a ground plane split can have over those signals, but I'm unsure if this also applies on a power plane. 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It applies to any plane underneath the signal.

If you don't want or can't tolerate those effects, have your signal route over a continuous reference plane. If you absolutely have to cross the gap, and there is no way around it, you can use stitching capacitors to cross planes.

[image]

I would place two caps on either side of the signal, as close as possible to the signal trace.

Stitching capacitors make the best of a bad situation (like getting stabbed, and having a doctor nearby). But the best, is not to cross the gap (don't get stabbed).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, it really helped me clarify this situation. I have another question, if there is a solid ground plane in between the signal's and the power plane, will that reduce the effects?

Comment: @erickorozco The signal's return will travel on the reference plane. The reference plane is closest plane to the signal. A plane is a relatively large continuous sheet of copper at a uniform potential (it can be 0V, 12V, 24V, 1.2V...etc.). Any other plane that is not the reference plane for the signal would not matter because you would be disrupting the coupling between the signal and the reference plane.

Comment: The OP is asking about a differential pair even though the OPs image doesn't make that obvious.  This answer from @efox29 is absolutely correct if the question was WRT single ended signals, but I'm not convinced of the accuracy of this answer for diff pairs.  When considering diff pairs, the signal and return paths are the diff pairs themselves.  Obviously, impedance mismatches occur when routing diff pairs over split planes so this should be avoided whenever possible, but i think the question remains...  How are diff pair signals affected in the case where this situation is unavoidable?

Comment: @AJbotic just to add a bit of a side thing  - diff routing is non sense. Routing differential lines as single ended lines with similiar-ish length matching is more than enough. I took a class taught by Lee Ritchey, and he was able to achieve 32 GHz signals by routing his differential signals traces as single ended. The coupling is between signal and plane. The whole near and far coupling appears to not really be a concern according to Lee Ritchey, Eric Bogatin and Rick Hartley (all of which have taught at PCB West).

Comment: @efox29 Thanks for the response.  Yes, I am privy to the experts you've referenced and I value their contributions.  I agree that optimal speeds can be achieved with single ended topologies, and I don't contend that speed is the primary motivator for using differential signaling.  I see the lack of a need for a common reference as the most beneficial point which cleans up the system ground diagram significantly, making it easier to avoid ground loops and dictate current paths better.

Comment: continued... But these points I think are beside the point here... In a system where we must interface high speed diff pair signal like GigE, LVDS, USB 3.0, and others, how can we expect impedance discontinuities to affect our diff pair signals?  It is clearly not negligible, especially in the >1gbps regime.  Check out this paper if you have the means... https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6320490